# Dockerfile ARG not expanding as key,value pair

Tags: docker

I have an image that has long directives , but for conciseness I will just place here the offending lines:

```
FROM python:3

ARG UID=10001
RUN adduser \
    --disabled-password \
    --gecos "" \
    --home "/home/airflow" \
    --shell "/bin/bash" \
    --uid "${UID}" \
    airflow

USER airflow

RUN --mount=type=cache,target=/root/.cache/pip  \
    --mount=type=secret,id=nexus3,target=/etc/nexus3.crt,uid=$UID,required=true
```

I get this error:

```
failed to solve with frontend dockerfile.v0: failed to create LLB definition: dockerfile parse error line 30: invalid value $UID for uid
```

So my UID cannot expand , why ?

Comment: call your variable `MYUID` or something, `UID` clashes with Linux's environment variable

Comment: but the first --uid "${UID}" expands normally

Comment: Use double quotes around the argument?

Comment: I tried that to, no avail

Comment: maybe mount directive does not accept variable substitution ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`RUN` lines do not themselves replace environment variables.  See [Environment replacement](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#environment-replacement) in the Dockerfile documentation; `RUN` is not on the list of directives supported.

The normal expectation is that `RUN` commands will invoke a shell, and that shell will do environment expansion.  (`RUN` supports an exec form with a JSON-array command like `CMD` but it's rarely used.)  If you go back in Docker history, `RUN --docker-options` are a relatively recent addition.  I think environment substitution just isn't supported here.

The container-private user ID is typically an implementation detail.  This turns out to be a place you actually need to know it, but in most cases I typically let **adduser**(8) pick the ID for me, and I would avoid passing it as a build-time `ARG`.

Depending on what you're doing, some possible workarounds are:

- Do this install step as root.  Often you need to install software as root and then switch to the non-root user at the end of the Dockerfile.

  ```sh
  RUN --mount=type=secret ...  # without uid=
  USER airflow                 # after the `RUN`
  ```
- Make the secret world-readable (but still only for the duration of the `RUN` command).  This could interfere with some particularly picky tools; `ssh` wants a secret key to be mode 0400 exactly.

  ```sh
  RUN --mount=type=secret,mode=0444 ...  # without uid=
  ```
- Hard-code the uid where you need it.

  ```sh
  # no ARG UID
  RUN adduser ... --uid 10001 ...
  RUN --mount=type=secret,uid=10001 ...  # hard-coding the uid
  ```